# Video uploads and conversions in Elixir Phoenix

Tags: video, elixir, phoenix-framework

Does anyone knows how to do video uploads and conversions in Phoenix? I want to give my users an ability to upload videos which can be viewed on any platform.

I hear that the video's would need to be converted to multiple formats for them to be viewable on multiple platforms. Any pointers and code examples will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) for the video conversion. This is platform agnostic, so you can roll out your own solution, similar to how `arc` integrates with ImageMagic.

However, videos are a tricky business. Not only you need to convert to formats that are viewable on multiple platforms, it is also good user experience to support multiple resolutions and serve the appropriate one based on the quality of the user's connection. You should also look into player support.

I would recommend looking into third party apps that can handle conversion, hosting and serving of videos for you. I use [Vimeo Pro](https://vimeo.com/pro) and am very pleased with their service and they have great API documentation. Another option would be [Wistia](http://wistia.com).

Comment: Wow! Thats great information. Can you share a link to your website, i would like to see how the experience of the user is.

Comment: Is there a vimeo-client (hex)-package available, or have you build a custom solution. Would be great if you could share some key parts

Comment: I have built my own however a quick search showed that this [package](https://github.com/lilfaf/vimeo.ex) can be used to interact with the Vimeo API